# Add amount of children to parent page menu item in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu, parent, menuitem, children

I have a menu with 10 parent pages in Wordpress. Each parent page have alot of children (sub-pages). I would like to append to each menu item a number showing how many children that item has.

EXAMPLE:

**Standard menu:** Products | Portfolio | Store | Jobs

**Menu i want:** Products (49) | Portfolio (14) | Store (22) | Jobs (51)

This indicates that the parent page "Products" has 49 children. "Portfolio" has 14 etc. Adding new sub-pages to these parent pages would automatically update the number.

I am using the default menu that wordpress creates of your pages, and not the menu-system found under apperance. Using TwentyThirteen theme.

Anyone?

Anders

Comment: What is the function you are using to display the menu?

Comment: I am using the standard TwentyThirteen function to display it 

<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such case you can use the `walker`. Put the following class in your `functions.php` file

```
class themeslug_walker_nav_menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    // add main/sub classes to li's and links
    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $indent = ( $depth > 0 ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent

        // depth dependent classes
        $depth_classes = array(
            ( $depth == 0 ? 'main-menu-item' : 'sub-menu-item' ),
            ( $depth >=2 ? 'sub-sub-menu-item' : '' ),
            ( $depth % 2 ? 'menu-item-odd' : 'menu-item-even' ),
            'menu-item-depth-' . $depth
        );
        $depth_class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', $depth_classes ) );

        // passed classes
        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) ) );

        // build html
        $output .= $indent . '<li id="nav-menu-item-'. $item->ID . '" class="' . $depth_class_names . ' ' . $class_names . '">';

        // link attributes
        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ' class="menu-link ' . ( $depth > 0 ? 'sub-menu-link' : 'main-menu-link' ) . '"';
        $childs = count(get_pages('child_of='.$item->object_id.'&parent='.$item->object_id));
        $item_output = sprintf( '%1$s<a%2$s>%3$s%4$s (%5$s) %6$s</a>%7$s',
            $args->before,
            $attributes,
            $args->link_before,
            apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ),
            $childs,
            $args->link_after,
            $args->after
        );

        // build html
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

and add this walker in your `wp_nav_menu` function

`<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu', 'walker' => new themeslug_walker_nav_menu ) ); ?>`

That's it.

Comment: This seems to "almost" work for me. Every menu item is replaced by the following: (121)

That number does not add up to the number of pages i have or anything, so there must be something wrong with this code. Any ideas?

Comment: About the same thing happens with this code to. Now every menu item is replaced på (37), which is the number of parent pages i have at this moment of testing. I have currently over 140 child pages spread among those 37 parent pages.

Comment: Can you give me the link where I can check it?

Comment: Sorry, it is a sensetive page with alot of customer information, but i can provide you with a screenshot that shoul at least visualy show what i want. http://www.effektivhjemmeside.no/menu_child_amount.jpg

Comment: Okay. This screenshot is with `walker` included in you `wp_nav_menu` or without `walker` ?

Comment: Without walker. With the walker, the text on every parent page menu item is changed to (37), and also, it seems every child page that exists in every parent page is also listed with (39). Here is a screenshot form the same parent page as before, but with the walker activated: http://www.effektivhjemmeside.no/menu_with_walker.png

Comment: It seems like you haven't added menus/pages in `primary` menu from `wp-admin`. You will have to add all `parent pages` in `primary` menu. to do so go in `Appearance > Menus` and create 1 menu and all parent pages in that menu. That's all. Now walker will work as desired to work.

Comment: :) That's great. You can accept this answer as correct answer and vote up if you want.